# Parsing XML with Python - accessing elements

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, lxml

I'm using lxml to parse some xml, but for some reason I can't find a specific element.

I'm trying to access the `<Constant>` elements.

Here's an xml snippet:

```
  </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
        </MiriamAnnotation>
        <ListOfSubstrates>
          <Substrate metabolite="Metabolite_5" stoichiometry="1"/>
        </ListOfSubstrates>
        <ListOfModifiers>
          <Modifier metabolite="Metabolite_9" stoichiometry="1"/>
        </ListOfModifiers>
        <ListOfConstants>
          <Constant key="Parameter_4344" name="Kcat" value="433.724"/>
          <Constant key="Parameter_4343" name="km" value="479.617"/>
```

The code I'm using is like this:

```
    >>> from lxml import etree as ET
    >>> parsed = ET.parse('ct.cps')
    >>> root = parsed.getroot()    
    >>> for a in root.findall(".//Constant"):
    ...     print a.attrib['key']
    ... 
    >>> for a in root.findall('Constant'):
    ...     print a.get('key')
    ... 
    >>> for a in root.findall('Constant'):
    ...     print a.attrib['key']
    ...
```

As you can see, none of these things seem to work.

What am I doing wrong?

---

EDIT: I'm wondering if it has something to do with the fact that `<Constant>` elements are empty?

---

**EDIT2: Source xml here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/i6hga7nvmcd6rxx/ct.cps?dl=0**

Comment: I guess it has to do with namespace. You need to take care of the namespace part.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean, I will try.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how you can get the values you are looking for:

```
from lxml import etree

parsed = etree.parse('ct.cps')

for a in parsed.findall("//{http://www.copasi.org/static/schema}Constant"):
    print a.attrib["key"]
```

Output:

```
Parameter_4344
Parameter_4343
Parameter_4342
Parameter_4341
Parameter_4340
Parameter_4339
Parameter_4338
Parameter_4337
Parameter_4336
Parameter_4335
Parameter_4334
Parameter_4333
Parameter_4332
Parameter_4331
Parameter_4330
Parameter_4329
Parameter_4328
Parameter_4327
Parameter_4326
Parameter_4325
Parameter_4324
Parameter_4323
Parameter_4322
Parameter_4321
Parameter_4320
Parameter_4319
```

The important thing here is that the `COPASI` root element in your XML file (the real one at the Dropbox URL) declares a default namespace (`http://www.copasi.org/static/schema`). This means that the element and all its descendants, including `Constant`, belong to that namespace.

So instead of `Constant` elements, you need to look for `{http://www.copasi.org/static/schema}Constant` elements.

See http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#namespaces.

---

Here is how you could do it using XPath instead of `findall`:

```
from lxml import etree

NSMAP = {"c": "http://www.copasi.org/static/schema"}

parsed = etree.parse('ct.cps')

for a in parsed.xpath("//c:Constant", namespaces=NSMAP):
    print a.attrib["key"]
```

See http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#namespaces-and-prefixes.

Comment: Wow!! I had an annoying problem with parsing since hours and by pure luck I foind out the source of my problem is exactly the namespace one! Thanks so much!

Comment: @user9589: I'm glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

First, please disregard my comment. It turns out that `xml.etree` is much better than the standard `xml.etree.ElementTree` in that it takes care of the namespace. The problem you have is you want to search for `'//Constant'`, which means the nodes can be at any level. However, the root element does not allow you to do it:

```
>>> root.findall('//Constant')
SyntaxError: cannot use absolute path on element
```

However, you can do that at higher level:

```
>>> parsed.findall('//Constant')
[<Element Constant at 0x10a7ce128>, <Element Constant at 0x10a7ce170>]
```

## Update

I am posting here the full text. Since I don't have your full XML file, I make something up to fill in the blank.

```
from lxml import etree as ET
from StringIO import StringIO

xml_text = """<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>

<rdf:root  xmlns:rdf='http://foo.bar.com/rdf'>
<rdf:RDF>
  <rdf:Description>
    DescriptionX
  </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
<rdf:foo>
        <MiriamAnnotation>
          bar
        </MiriamAnnotation>
        <ListOfSubstrates>
          <Substrate metabolite="Metabolite_5" stoichiometry="1"/>
        </ListOfSubstrates>
        <ListOfModifiers>
          <Modifier metabolite="Metabolite_9" stoichiometry="1"/>
        </ListOfModifiers>
        <ListOfConstants>
          <Constant key="Parameter_4344" name="Kcat" value="433.724"/>
          <Constant key="Parameter_4343" name="km" value="479.617"/>
        </ListOfConstants>
</rdf:foo>
</rdf:root>
"""

buffer = StringIO(xml_text)
tree = ET.parse(buffer)
for constant_node in tree.findall('//Constant'):
    print constant_node.attrib['key']
```

Comment: I thought that `lxml` is better than elementtree with regards to namespaces because I had namespace errors when using the latter and theyre now sorted. However, the first error is removed by putting a `.` before the first backslash though... and it still doesn't work. As for the second suggestion, I still can't access attribute values using that code: nothing is outputted

Comment: I think that it might be something to do with the fact that the `<Constant>` elements are empty elements, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `findall`.  It is has a limited featureset and is designed to be compatible with `ElementTree`.

Instead, use `xpath`, which supports namespaces.   From the above, it appears that you probably want to say something like

```
# possibilities, you need to get these right...
ns_dict = {'atom':"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom",,
    "rdf":"http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#" }

root = parsed.getroot()    
for a in root.xpath('.//rdf:Constant', namespaces=ns_dict):
    print a.attrib['key']
```

Note that you *must* include a namespace prefix in your `xpath` expression whenever an element has a non-blank namespace, and they must map to one of the namespace URLs that match the same URLs in your document.

### Update

Since you posted your original document, I see that there is no namespace assigned to the elements you are looking for.  This will work, I just tried it with your source document:

```
for a in tree.xpath("//Constant"):
    print a.attrib['key']
```

You don't need a namespace because there is no default namespace specified in the document itself.

Comment: Thanks. How do I find out the element's namespace? EDIT: I'm sure that rdf is the namespace but your code still isnt working

Comment: Note that "rdf" is just a namespace prefix.  My `rdf:Constant` refers to the namespace in `ns_dict`.  Namespaces must be explicitly declared inside your source document and are inherited by subelements.   Look for the `xmlns` declarations in containing elements.   For example, if a containing element has `xmlns=` it defines the default namespace for any unadorned subelement, whereas "xmlns:xxx=" defines the namespace for the 'xxx' prefix.

Also, it doesn't matter what the prefix was in your source document.  `lxml` rewrites them all internally, so you need to remap them.

Comment: So the rdf term will be a url?

Comment: Yes, namespaces are specified as URLs in the source document's `xmlns` attributes.  The prefixes are just mappings, and the source document prefixes will not be preserved.  `ET.parse` will convert all prefixes to internal, explicit references to the namespace URLs, and you need to use a namespace map like `ns_dict` in my example in order to re-establish a new set of prefixes for use in `xpath`.

Comment: You can get a list of the namespaces used by your source document by using `parsed.getroot().nsmap`.  If you print that out, you'll see what namespaces are defined in your document.

Comment: OK. Thank you for all the help. So do I need to use the same namespace URL in the map and in the `rdf` term before the element that I desire; should the namespace map URL be a URL from my source?

Comment: `parsed.getroot().nsmap` gives just one namespace: `>>> print parsed.getroot().nsmap
{None: 'http://www.copasi.org/static/schema'}`

Comment: See my above update.  The namespaces behavior is as I describe, but now that I see your source document, it's obvious the elements you are looking for have no namespace, and there is no default namespace assigned in any containing element.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't yet posted the source document - that was just the namespace URL. Source is here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/i6hga7nvmcd6rxx/ct.cps?dl=0

Comment: The code doesn't work unfortunately - I get no output

Comment: I would be suspicious of some other problem.  Using Python 2.7, I cut and pasted your code exactly from the update below, then ran the code in my update.  I got two lines, one said "Parameter_4344" the other said "Parameter_4343".

Comment: The update code only works with the snippet, not with the source that I posted.

Comment: *there is no default namespace specified in the document itself*. This is wrong. The `COPASI` root element in the XML file at the Dropbox URL does declare a namespace.